# Faraday::ConnectionFailed in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application was working fine until a few minutes ago, I get the following error:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed in Devise::SessionsController#create
Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)
```

I tried searching and found this might be related to elastic search. So I did the following:

```
$ curl localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

$ brew services start elasticsearch
Service `elasticsearch` already started, use `brew services restart elasticsearch` to restart.
```

Nothing has changed, it still not working.

I guess there could be multiple sources for the problem. Does anybody knows how to investigate and fix this one please?
The rest of the app works well, but everything that has to do with searchkick in the model, creates that issue.

Below is the log from console:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"uaT1nvIHefWongRLepHPoXy5h5gihEh+0ymBaujsenamdkis/lRiB2Yhnsbnr6xkmDPRwJDURXvV9NSm8A==", "locale"=>"en"}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "2c99733a-4ae0-42f8-97ba-9e4287d7c1cf"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
           ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2  [["taggable_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "User"]]
           (0.2ms)  COMMIT

User Store (7.1ms)  {"id":"2c99893a-4ae0-47f8-97ba-9e4487d7c1cf","exception":["Faraday::ConnectionFailed","Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for \"localhost\" port 9200)"],"exception_object":"Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for \"localhost\" port 9200)"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (Searchkick: 7.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)



Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)):

    /Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939:in `rescue in block in connect'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:936:in `block in connect'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:1455:in `request'
faraday (0.15.4) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `perform_request'
faraday (0.15.4) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:43:in `block in call'
faraday (0.15.4) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:92:in `with_net_http_connection'
faraday (0.15.4) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `call'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
faraday (0.15.4) lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:143:in `build_response'
faraday (0.15.4) lib/faraday/connection.rb:387:in `run_request'
elasticsearch-transport (6.2.0) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:23:in `block in perform_request'
elasticsearch-transport (6.2.0) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:266:in `perform_request'
elasticsearch-transport (6.2.0) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
elasticsearch-transport (6.2.0) lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:143:in `perform_request'
elasticsearch-api (6.2.0) lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:85:in `bulk'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/indexer.rb:18:in `perform'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:126:in `perform'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/indexer.rb:11:in `queue'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/bulk_indexer.rb:43:in `bulk_index'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/index.rb:125:in `store'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:28:in `block in store'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:27:in `store'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/record_indexer.rb:74:in `reindex_record'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/record_indexer.rb:51:in `reindex'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/model.rb:78:in `reindex'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:260:in `block in conditional'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:343:in `committed!'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:86:in `commit_records'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:178:in `block in commit_transaction'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:168:in `commit_transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:207:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/etiennelandro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'
devise (4.6.1) lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb:62:in `forget_me!'
devise (4.6.1) lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb:32:in `forget_me'
devise (4.6.1) lib/devise/hooks/forgetable.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/hooks.rb:15:in `block in _run_callbacks'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `each'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `_run_callbacks'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:52:in `_run_callbacks'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/proxy.rb:274:in `block in logout'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/proxy.rb:272:in `each'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/proxy.rb:272:in `logout'
devise (4.6.1) lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb:98:in `sign_out_all_scopes'
devise (4.6.1) lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb:81:in `sign_out'
devise (4.6.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:28:in `destroy'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
searchkick (3.1.2) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.6.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.6.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
rollbar (2.19.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:24:in `block in call'
rollbar (2.19.2) lib/rollbar.rb:146:in `scoped'
rollbar (2.19.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/rollbar.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
rollbar (2.19.2) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I just tried reindexing a table :

```
2.5.3 :001 > Event.reindex
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200))
```

I just found by searching that it could be related to memory. NOt sure how to check it, also THE APP IS WORKING PERFECTLY FINE ON HEROKU, so the problem is local, but I need to fix it for sure.

(edited question)
I just ran elasticsearch from terminal, and it returns the following:

```
$ elasticsearch
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

[2019-05-07T11:41:56,649][WARN ][o.e.c.l.LogConfigurator  ] [unknown] Some logging configurations have %marker but don't have %node_name. We will automatically add %node_name to the pattern to ease the migration for users who customize log4j2.properties but will stop this behavior in 7.0. You should manually replace `%node_name` with `[%node_name]%marker ` in these locations:
  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/log4j2.properties
[2019-05-07T11:41:57,948][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Uqr3VHG] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [386.7gb], net total_space [464.6gb], types [hfs]
[2019-05-07T11:41:57,948][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Uqr3VHG] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2019-05-07T11:41:58,748][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] node name derived from node ID [Uqr3VHGpQTmcyJav-f-6RQ]; set [node.name] to override
[2019-05-07T11:41:58,748][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] version[6.7.0], pid[29217], build[oss/tar/8453f77/2019-03-21T15:32:29.844721Z], OS[Mac OS X/10.13.6/x86_64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_192/25.192-b12]
[2019-05-07T11:41:58,749][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/c_/cqbnlqbx5lq7vjgf31_wsgvh0000gp/T/elasticsearch-6333526767767413674, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Des.path.home=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.7.0/libexec, -Des.path.conf=/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=oss, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,279][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,280][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,281][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,281][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,281][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [parent-join]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,281][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [percolator]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,281][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,281][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [reindex]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,282][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [repository-url]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,282][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,282][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] loaded module [tribe]
[2019-05-07T11:42:01,283][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Uqr3VHG] no plugins loaded
[2019-05-07T11:42:08,927][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [Uqr3VHG] using discovery type [zen] and host providers [settings]
[2019-05-07T11:42:09,753][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] initialized
[2019-05-07T11:42:09,753][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] starting ...
[2019-05-07T11:42:10,495][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Uqr3VHG] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
ERROR: Cluster name [elasticsearch_etiennelandro] subdirectory exists in data paths [/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_etiennelandro]. All data under these paths must be moved up one directory to paths [/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch]
[2019-05-07T11:42:10,561][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] stopping ...
[2019-05-07T11:42:10,589][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] stopped
[2019-05-07T11:42:10,590][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] closing ...
[2019-05-07T11:42:10,614][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Uqr3VHG] closed
```

Additional information:
When i removed `searchick world_middle: [:first_name]` from my model, and restart the server, the user can login without any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run `elasticsearch` you get the following error

```
ERROR: Cluster name [elasticsearch_etiennelandro] subdirectory exists in data paths [/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_etiennelandro]. All data under these paths must be moved up one directory to paths [/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch]
```

as explained from [`xeraa`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573153/xeraa) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55443457/7295772)

> Did you have an older version (2.x or before) installed before? It sounds a lot like this [PR to check that you're not using the old behavior when there was the node name in the path](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/36519).
>
> What I would do:
>
> - If you don't need the data any more, just remove
>     /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_nikitavlasenko and
>     start fresh.
> - If you need the data, you could either change path.data in your
>     config or move the folder one level up (just like the log message
>     says).
>
> PS: I wouldn't use port 9300 for HTTP, because that's generally the port used for communication of the nodes in a cluster itself.

also consider reading their comments and relevant posts from that page, for example the one from [Franz Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847338/franz-kafka)

> Turns out that the config file points to /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch for the data path, but the package creates the directory /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_USERNAME. Since that elasticsearch_USERNAME directory is in there, it fails to start. I resolved the error by simply removing the elasticsearch_USERNAME directory as you suggested.

The error crashes your `elastichsearch` server which should be running on `localhost:9200`

Comment: ...i just had to delete the folder elasticsearch_USERNAME indeed,...as I reported myself. Almost too easy and cost me 50pts :)

Comment: Sorry actually this fix the error in elasticsearch but does not fix the main error actually

Comment: @Etienne :) I can be helpful so be sure to contact me with some clear explanation of your problems and create a new question for your new issues and tag me with at FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: You fix it, i need to wait 17 hr to give you the bounty, what the stackoverflow site says. THANK YOU.